# Adding automatic filters on a list in SP Online when the user access the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I'm kind of new to SP online.
I have a question related to workflows that I don`t even know if it's possible.

I want to create a workflow on a list that automatically filters the information based on the User that accesses that list.

E.g.: If I access that list, automatically filter my name and show all information based on my userID.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do you could simple use the [me] filter option on the view.

The field needs to be a people field for it to work. Mind you it does not work for groups.

You don't need a workflow for this.

Comment: Now I realize it was a dumb question.
Thank you very much for your support ! It works

Comment: Glad to help :)